# UTF chars retrieved with AJAX are not shown in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, escaping

I have problem rendering content retrieved via Ajax into my HTML page under Safari (v.4).
The page is stored in UTF-8, Ajax response is also UTF-8 encoded.

The loaded content is parsed and then different types of lists are populated with the parsed data. 
One of them is simple < select > element where the text of the option is set using trivial code:

```
option.innerHTML = "";
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
```

My text contains french characters. 
As a result of the code above the < select > element shows option with this french text split in 2 parts, where the separator (some cool french letter) is not shown at all... :(

Using

```
option.innerHTML = escapeGtLtAmp(text);
```

has same result.

If the french content is set to innerHTML of some < div > then the text is shown not split but simply with non-english letters omitted.

Under Firefox 2 things seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you please post a link to a (minimal) sample page that exhibits this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The page is stored in UTF-8, Ajax response is also UTF-8 encoded.

Does the AJAX-response also have the Content-Type-HTTP-header set to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, response Content-Type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Firefox 3, and it seemed that the problem was the ajax call. I also tried changing the request headers but problem continued. So I tried loading the data from an iframe thereby avoiding ajax altogether, and then getting the iframe's innerHTML.

If you're using jquery, perhaps [this little plugin](http://www.nicolas.rudas.info/jQuery/xajaSubmit.js) could help you or just give you an idea